# Linear Algebra. Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ denote the vector space of real $n×n$ matrices and
$f : M → \mathbb{R}$ be a linear transformation such that $f(AB) = f(BA)$
for all $A, B ∈ M$. Define $C = (c_{ij})$ to be the matrix in $M$ such that
$$
c_{ij} = (1/\sqrt{2})^{i+j}.
$$
If $f(C) = 1$, then express $f(I_n)$ as a function on $n$.

I did  $AB= BA$ because $f$ is linear transformation. Next step I don't know.

Comment: You don't know that $AB = BA$; all you know is that for any two matrices, $A$ and $B$, we have $f(AB - BA) = 0$. You might consider the case $n = 1$ and see exactly what the function $f$ must be, and then try $n = 2$. When you've done those two, you'll have more insight into the general problem.

Comment: By the way, do your indices $i$ and $j$ go from $0$ to $n-1$ or from $1$ to $n$?

Comment: i and j go from 1 to n. f(aA) = af(A). a= 0 -> f(0) =0. so AB = BA? doesn't it?

Comment: When you write $f(0) = 0$, that doesn't mean that $f(X) = 0 $ *implies* that $X = 0$; it means that $X = 0$ implies $f(X) = 0$. Consider, for instance, $F(X) = x_{11}$. That's linear, and it's zero when $X$ is the zero matrix, but *also* when $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

By assumption
$$
f(A B - B A) = 0
$$
for all matrices $A, B$.

Now the set of matrices $AB-BA$ is exactly the set of matrices of trace zero, a subspace of codimension $1$ of the space of matrices.

So you know that
$$
f(R)
=
1,
$$
where
$$
R =\begin{bmatrix}
r^{2} \\
& r^{4}\\
& & \ddots \\
& & & r^{2n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $r = 1/\sqrt{2}$, and blank entries are zeroes. Let $s = r^{2} + \dots + r^{2n} = \text{trace}(R)$.

Then
$$
\text{trace}\left(\frac{n}{s} \cdot R\right) = n = \text{trace}(I_{n}),
$$
so that
$$
0 = f\left( I_{n} -  \frac{n}{s} \cdot R\right) = f(I_{n}) - \frac{n}{s}.
$$